# What is the maximal normalized number and what is the maximal not normalized number that can be represented using IEEE-754 Single?

Tags: floating-point, max, normalization, ieee-754

I would love to understand the answers to these queastions :

What is the maximal not normalized number that can be represented using IEEE-754 Single ?

What is the maximal normalized number that can be represented using IEEE-754 Single ?

Comment: The first step consist in learning how these floating point numbers are represented... Then you will be able to devise the limits. By doing so, you'll have understood the questions and will be able to provide the answers by yourself. Understanding the answers to the questions directly without even starting by learning the premises sounds unrealistic...

Answer (score 1):

> ... to understand the answers to these questions :

Look at the number in its bit pattern and review [IEEE-754 Single](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) with its 8 bit biased exponent, and its 23-bit fraction.

Also, look at it with a hexadecimal significant and decimal power-of-2 exponent.  In C, this is done with `printf("%a", x);`

---

> What is the maximal normalized number that can be represented using IEEE-754 Single ?

```
v--------------------------------- Sign
  v------v------------------------ 8 bit biased exponent - max value for finite numbers
           v---------------------v Fraction part of 1.xxx...xxx significand - max value
0 11111110 11111111111111111111111

  v------v-------- All 23 bits of the encoded significand and the implied 1.  
            v-v--- Maximum exponent for finite numbers.    
0x1.fffffep+127

In decimal
printf("%.9e\n", pow(2,128) - pow(2,128-24));
3.402823466e+38  (approximate)
340282346638528859811704183484516925440   (exact)
```

> What is the maximal not normalized number that can be represented using IEEE-754 Single ?

```
v--------------------------------- Sign
  v------v------------------------ 8 bit minimum exponent - same as 1 - bias
           v---------------------v Fraction part of 0.xxx...xxx significand  - max value
0 00000000 11111111111111111111111

  v------v-------- All 23 bits of the encoded significand and no implied 1. 
            v-v--- Maximum exponent for finite numbers.    
0x1.fffffcp-127

In decimal
printf("%.9e\n", pow(2,-126) - pow(2,-126-23));
1.175494211e-38  (approximate)
```

.

```
(exact) 
1.175494210692441075487029444849287348827052428745893333857174530571588870475618904265502351336181163787841796875e-38
```

---

Note: rarely are exact decimal values needed.  Values rounded to 9 leading significant decimal digits are sufficient to differentiate all the possible IEEE-754 single.